# Get random record from database with Zapier

Tags: zapier

I want to build an action in Zapier that winds up sending a random email. The body of the email would be randomly pulled from any source that would be appropriate for storing HTML. I was thinking Google Sheets or Knack.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to ask Zapier to get a random record from the source.

Have any of you done something similar?

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

It really depends on how you store that data. Your first step is probably to add a code step that generates a [random integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). From there, you need a way to turn that id into a piece of data. In the case of sheets, you could put each HTML in a row and give it an "id" of an integer. Then, do a search to find the row with the random ID and pull the data out of that row.

Alternatively (depending on how much data you're storing), you could use [Storage by Zapier](https://zapier.com/help/storeclient-javascript/) and a code step to do the whole process.

Hopefully that points you in the right direction!

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, David. I was trying to think of how I would retrieve a count of total rows in my Google Sheet to help with my random integer. One thing I thought of was to tally those as they are created and retrieve from Storage by Zapier. Does that seem feasible or should I look for a more graceful method?

Comment: If you're generating the entries programmatically and don't plan on deleting often (or are also doing that programmatically), that seems like a great way to do it! Storage has an `increment` function that'll make your life pretty easy.